# Unable to integrate angular-chronicle in my angularjs project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added the `chronicle.js` file as a library in my angular-js project.
But when I try to inject it in a controller, I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ChronicleProvider <- Chronicle
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/unpr?p0=ChronicleProvider%20%3C-%20Chronicle
    at angular.js:79
    at angular.js:3557
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:3684)
    at angular.js:3562
    at getService (angular.js:3684)
    at invoke (angular.js:3711)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3732)
    at angular.js:6849
    at angular.js:6231
    at forEach (angular.js:312)
```

There's no syntax issue.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? I am new to AngularJS.

Comment: Unknown provider issue. make sure js of this is loaded and you have specified it in dependencies for your controller.

Comment: make sure that you load the chronicle.js file

Comment: I have added it like this `<script src="lib/angular-chronicle/chronicle.js"></script>` but doesn't work. @aitnasser @Jitendra Khatri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this working demo [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0n0qcRDfIjNFST1iR6Xr?p=preview)  that can help you

```
.
```

Comment: does it mean I have to use chronicle as a factory?

Comment: no ,here just an example,but in the same way that the factory here has been implemented we can implement all other components (service, provider...)

Comment: I hadn't injected Chronicle in my module, thanks the demo helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try a './' at the beginning of your script tag, like so:

```
<script src="./lib/angular-chronicle/chronicle.js"></script>
```

One way or other, presuming you followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Blitzen/Angular-Chronicle) correctly, I believe your application is just having trouble finding the library. It seems to know what it should be looking for to begin with.